# Opening first WPF window is slow in VSTO add-in

Tags: wpf, performance, vsto, office-addins

I have developed a VSTO PowerPoint add-in that uses WPF for UI.
The first time the user opens a WPF window after PowerPoint has started, it takes a lot of time to load (5 seconds for a normal window).
After opening this first window, if I open any other window it loads twice as fast as the first window opening.
The same happens even if my window is empty and contains no resources.

Any idea how to speed up opening of the first WPF window?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is expected - .Net runtime and WPF need to be loaded and initialized before you can do anything. And initializing them in a background thread is probably not an option since WPF has a main thread affinity.